# create and understand the operation of a horizontal menu in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, url

Good morning guys, I'm new to CodeIgniter, 
I want to create a horizontal menu, I've done this with HTML + CSS3, and when I click on the menu it goes to that page indicated, of course, using html, but I want to do in CodeIgniter. 
I've found the documentation, but it was not clear to me 
https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/url_helper.html 
can someone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creating a horizontal menu in CodeIgniter is a lot like creating it with plan HTML, only you're using CI helpers to create the anchors. A simple menu would be created like this:

```
<ul id="menu">
    <li><?php echo anchor('controller/action', 'Link Text'); ?></li>
    <li><?php echo anchor('controller/action', 'Link Two'); ?></li>
    <li><?php echo anchor('controller/action', 'Link Three'); ?></li>
</ul>
```

The `anchor` helper will produce a link, so your menu items will output like this:

```
<li><a href="controller/action">Link Text</a></li>
```

Once you create the menu you can style it with CSS like any other menu. In place of the `anchor` helper you can use any of the other URL helpers like `current_url` or `index_page`.

You're not required to use the URL helpers when creating a menu, so if you have a static menu you could use plain HTML to create it.